# Clear stack activities from specific activity with eventBus

Tags: java, android, greenrobot-eventbus

I would like to know if it's possible to clear all activities from an old one. I would like to use enventBus to do this.

**Example of a stack of activities:**

```
startActivity(A) then startActivity(B) then startActivity(C) then startActivity(D)...
```

Activity B is registered onEvent(ClearStackFromHere()) with eventBus.

And from Activity D I want to post the event post(new ClearStackFromHere) with eventBus too.

So, is it possible to clear the stack of activities from B ?

What should I write inside my ClearStackFromHere().

Thanks,

Comment: I don't think this is possible because activity B is not active when you want to clear the stack. Have you tried using startActivityForResult instead? Then you would be able to handle results and close activities in the order you want.

Comment: I have the feeling EventBus is not helping here. Maybe you could do something with sticky events, but please first think how you could do it without.

Comment: Ok so... I will see with onResult on each activities :-[ Thanks for answers

Answer (score 1):

I have implemented a similar solution in one of my projects.

What I needed was a way to keep only the most recent 3 activities in the back stack, and clear the others before them. This only applies to a certain Navigation flow within my application where it becomes possible that an infinite amount of Activities can be added to the back stack.

e.g. A opens B - which opens C, C can then open another instance of A or B... etc.

I should note that this solution uses EventBus 2.4.0 and there may be a better way to implement it with 3.0+.

First off, I defined a helper called `ActivityTracker`. It keeps track of what Activities are currently active, as well as an identifier for each activity. It also has methods that can be called to finish all activities in the back stack except for the most recent n amount.

```
public class ActivityTracker {

    private static ArrayList<String> activityStack = new ArrayList<>();

    //Notify the Tracker of a new Activity to track
    public static void activityActive(String uuid){
        addToBackStack(uuid);
    }

    //Notify the tracker of an Activity that should no longer be tracked 
    public static void finishing(String uuid){
        removeFromBackStack(uuid);
    }

    //Call this to clear entire back stack
    public static void killAllBackStackActivities(){
        killPreviousActivities(0);
    }

    //Call this to clear back stack while keeping most recent X amount
    private static void killPreviousActivities(int keepAmount){

        if(activityStack.size() <= keepAmount) {
            return;
        }

        //Copy to not manipulate while looping.
        String[] tempList = activityStack.toArray(new String[activityStack.size()]);

        int counter =  activityStack.size();
        for(String id : tempList){

            if(counter == keepAmount){
                return;
            }

            counter--;

            //Send notification to kill specific activity
            EventBus.getDefault().post(new ActivityShouldDieEvent(id));
        }
    }

    private static void addToBackStack(String uuid){
        if(!activityStack.contains(uuid)){
            activityStack.add(uuid);
            killPreviousActivities(3); //Always kill all activities except most recent 3.
        }
    }

    private static void removeFromBackStack(String uuid){
        if(activityStack.contains(uuid))
            activityStack.remove(uuid);
    }
}
```

Then, I defined a subclass of `AppCompatActivity` called `BackStackTrackActivity`. All relevant Activities in the app extend this class. The subclass looks like this:

```
public class BackStackTrackActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    //Random ID for activity to be identified by
    protected String uuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

    //Receive notification that activity should finish
    public void onEvent(ActivityShouldDieEvent ev){
        if(ev.getUuid().equals(this.uuid)){
            finish();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        //Unregister from EventBus
        EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);
        //Tell tracker to stop tracking
        ActivityTracker.finishing(uuid);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //Register for events
        EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
        //Tell tracker to track activity
        ActivityTracker.activityActive(uuid);
    }

}
```

With some work, I think you will be able to adapt this solution into something that meets your needs.

I hope that helps.